# jQueryUI sortable TableCells, with limit of cells per row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make my table grid sortable, but I have a limit of 3 items per row set up. But when you drag items from 1st row to 2nd row, then 1st row has only 2 items in it and 2nd one has 4 items there.

Is there some code, that would dynamically change the position of TR after the every Xth element?

Imitation:

**http://jsfiddle.net/xabxt3re/7/**

```
..
```

If you drag items in one row, its mostly OK, but if you try to drag it to next row, the table gets broken.

Any help?

I have to use the tables (no floats, divs or lits), so I need to fix this problem.

Thanks.